# Office.js: Increasingly poorer performance writing a large amount of rows to Excel

Tags: angular, office-js, excel-2016

I've got rows that are about 100 columns wide, but I'm only trying to write about 8000 rows. When I write out 3000 of these rows (in batches of 500) it consistently writes at a speed of about ~2-3 seconds per 500 rows.

However, when I try and write out a larger dataset containing 8000 rows of similar data (a few more columns), it performs just fine for about the first 3000 rows (about ~3-4 seconds per 500 rows), but starting around rows 2500 -3000 the performance gets increasingly slower and excel comes to a crawl. For example:

```
write rows address:  Sheet1!A3:DC502
batch write time:    3.0766400244386167  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A503:DC1002
batch write time:    3.3348399202363796  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A1003:DC1502
batch write time:    3.7307800745354034  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A1503:DC2002
batch write time:    4.149179874582915  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A2003:DC2502
batch write time:    3.8166401331085944  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A2503:DC3002
batch write time:    7.215600102149649  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A3003:DC3502
batch write time:    31.93173993128445  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A3503:DC4002
batch write time:    95.68281983804563  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A4003:DC4502
batch write time:    148.84947986377625  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A4503:DC5002
batch write time:    203.41412001861877  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A5003:DC5502
batch write time:    270.2974798251381  seconds
write rows address:  Sheet1!A5503:DC6002
...
```

The first 30 or so columns contain formulas and the cells have conditional formatting in them. The rest are just writing out data to plain white cells. I just hand the data to excel using range.values and it's what's taking so long. **What can I do to get stable performance?**

Here is my code:

```
async writeRows(data, formulas, sheetName, startCol, startRow) {
  return await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
    let sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName);
    let endRow = startRow;
    let startRowOffset = startRow;
    let batchSize = 500;
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + batchSize) {
      let t0 = performance.now();
      let min = Math.min(batchSize, data.length - i);
      let endCol = intToColumn(data[0].length);
      startRow = startRowOffset + i;
      endRow = startRow + min - 1;
      let address = sheetName + "!" + startCol + startRow + ":" + endCol + endRow;
      console.log("write rows address: ", address);
      let range = sheet.getRange(address);
      ctx.application.suspendApiCalculationUntilNextSync();
      range.values = data.slice(i, i + min)
      range.formulas = formulas.slice(i, i + min);
      await ctx.sync();
      let t1 = performance.now();
      console.log("batch write time: ", (t1 - t0) / 1000, ' seconds');
    }
    return endRow;
  });
}
```

If you're thinking it's just heavy formulas, here's the time for running the same rows without assigning anything to range.formulas:

```
batch write time:  2.072960040280297  seconds
batch write time:  1.893160016976646  seconds
batch write time:  2.239300093637197  seconds
batch write time:  2.4051598865728154  seconds
batch write time:  2.4535400113378855  seconds
batch write time:  4.228719875053808  seconds
batch write time:  21.932359953223656  seconds
batch write time:  65.58508005044697  seconds
batch write time:  99.76420028338683  seconds
batch write time:  133.58046007197566  seconds
batch write time:  181.46535997193905  seconds
...
```

Here is an screenshot from task manager:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can, try it in Excel too https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/. My guess would be that the conditional formatting and formulas are causing most of the delay, or a lot of data being transferred over the network by `.sync()`. https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/performance.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Biggest Problem:**

Not setting column formatting (`range.numberFormat`). Setting these first, before assigning the data to `range.values` made all the difference.

```
//Initial pass over every column to set types
if (type === "Date") {
    range.numberFormat = <any>'m/d/yyyy';
} else if (type === "Double") {
    range.numberFormat = <any>"#,##0.00";
} else {
    range.numberFormat = <any>"#";
}
```

**Final Times:**

Writing out in batches of 1000 rows with nice consistent times as you'd expect:

```
batch write time:  3.0076802402327596  seconds
batch write time:  3.0477398637461594  seconds
batch write time:  2.9507200432747487  seconds
batch write time:  3.0690198313384025  seconds
batch write time:  2.988500015243975  seconds
batch write time:  3.048739928042458  seconds
batch write time:  3.0736401102757082  seconds
batch write time:  3.097120038203488  seconds
batch write time:  2.068400111446943  seconds
```

**Other helpful changes:**

Initially, I built up my formulas cell by cell in a 2d array. For Example:

```
//explicity writing out each formula
range.formulas = [
                   [=A1+B1, =B2+C2],
                   [=A2+B2, =B2+C2],
                   ...
                   [=A100+B100, =B100+C100]
                 ];
```

The correct way to do this is:

```
//writing out formula for the first cell, and let excel expand it to the range.
let range = sheet.getRange('A1:A100');
range.formulas = '=A1+B1' as any 
let range2 = sheet.getRange('B1:B100');
range2.formulas = '=B1+C1' as any
```

Source: Thanks to @Slai for sharing this link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/performance.md

**Other:**

Since I was writing formulas to about the first 30 or so columns, initially, I wrote out the entire row from column A to column DC with null in the first 30 columns. I decided this was unnecessarily writing 30 columns of null values which likely would slow things down. Eventually, I decided to omit those null columns and only write out the columns with data.

I also played around with ctx.sync(), but being on the desktop version of Office 2016, I personally didn't notice too much of a difference one way or the other (inside the loop, outside, nested, etc). However, I would be a lot more concerned here if I were doing anything with Office online like @Rick Kirkham mentions in his link.

From reading this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/12#issuecomment-374741210, I also updated my desktop version of Excel to be later than build 9021.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `ctx.sync` inside a loop. That can be a performance killer. Try restructuring the method so that it writes everything with a single sync. It might help to see the pattern in my answer to this question: [Document not in sync after replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227941/document-not-in-sync-after-replace-text/48231976#48231976).

Answer (score 1):

I'm loading about 35k rows into officejs with a similar batching approach, but there haven't been much performance degradation between batches. 35 batches a 1000 lines take about 7 sec total:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
getWorksheetDataInChunks() {
    return ready.then(() => {
        return Excel.run(async (context) => {
            const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
            const dataRange = sheet
                .getUsedRange()
                .load('columnIndex, rowIndex, columnCount, rowCount, address');
            await context.sync();
            const rowsTotal = dataRange.rowCount;
            const batchSize = config.batchSize;
            const data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < rowsTotal; i += batchSize) {
                const chunk = `chunk${i / batchSize}`;
                const chunkStart = `${chunk}-start`;
                const chunkEnd = `${chunk}-end`;
                performance.mark(chunkStart);

                const rowsRemaining = rowsTotal - i;
                const rowOffset = rowsRemaining >= batchSize ? batchSize : rowsRemaining;
                const currentRange = sheet
                    .getCell(dataRange.rowIndex + i, dataRange.columnIndex)
                    .getResizedRange(rowOffset - 1, dataRange.columnCount - 1)
                    .load('values, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnCount, rowCount, address');
                await context.sync();
                data.push(...currentRange.values);

                performance.mark(chunkEnd);
                performance.measure(chunk, chunkStart, chunkEnd);
            }
            return data;
        }).catch(buildErrorHandler('getWorksheetDataInChunks'));
    });
},
```

Can you test if reading the data as slow as writing it?

You won't get by without a context.sync() inside your loop, because your way above the limit excel will handle in one sync. This is the only reason your doing the batching in the first place. Try to create a new context with Excel.run() for each loop iteration, maybe you can "cleanup" after the previous batch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know others among your tags but `excel` only. As I understood you try to push data in Excel. So, my advice - compose whole csv file on your side and export it to Excel or import it by Excel as bulk.
.

Comment: Thanks, but this is for an office.js add-in that I'm building and it's purpose is to write this data into excel. I removed the excel tag so hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @cs_pupil, OK. Over  :)