# Iterating over all paragraphs with content controls with Office Javascript API

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm trying to find every content control in a document, determine the paragraph it belongs to and perform some logic with it. To test, I created a document with four lines and a content control in every line. The code I've written is as follows:

```
    Word.run((context) => {
      const { contentControls } = context.document;
      contentControls.load('items');
      return context.sync().then(() => {
        contentControls.items.forEach((contentControl) => {
          const range = contentControl.getRange();
          range.load();
          context.sync().then(() => {
            const paragraphList = range.paragraphs;
            paragraphList.load();
            context.sync().then(() => {
              console.log(paragraphList.items[0].text);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

However, the result is some of the lines printing as expected while other lines throw the following error:

```
word-web-16.00.debug.js:12031 Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: The property 'items' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.
    at new RuntimeError (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:12031:22)
    at Function.Utility.createPropertyNotLoadedException (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:16760:11)
    at Utility.throwIfNotLoaded (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/word-web-16.00.debug.js:16756:19)
    at ParagraphCollection.get [as items]
```

I'm not sure why some of the lines containing content controls would have successfully loaded while others wouldn't.

My questions are:

1) Am I approaching this in the correct way, and

2) Why is the loading of the data so apparently idiosyncratic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems I see in your code:

1. You should avoid calling context.sync inside a loop. See my answer to: [document not in sync after replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227941/document-not-in-sync-after-replace-text/48231976#48231976). And see also, the sample file [Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker - service.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Angular2-StyleChecker/blob/master/app/services/word-document/word.document.service.js).
2. You have some "empty loads"; that is, calls of `load()` that pass no parameters. This will cause Office to unnecessarily load all scalar properties. You should load only the properties that your code is going to read. For example, `paragraphList.load()` should be `paragraphList.load("text")`.

Here's one way to do it that has only 2 `context.sync`s and neither is in a loop.

```
Word.run((context) => {
  const contentControls = context.document.contentControls.load("items");
  const rangesInContentControls = [];

  return context.sync()
  .then(() => {
      contentControls.items.forEach((contentControl) => {
      rangesInContentControls.push(contentControl.getRange().load("paragraphs/text"));
    }); 
  })
  .then(context.sync)
  .then(() => {
      rangesInContentControls.forEach((range) => {
      console.log(range.paragraphs.items[0].text);
    }); 
  })
});
```

Comment: Re: the empty loads: definitely. This was while I was still attempting to get a proof-of-concept working and wasn't yet worried about performance. And re: not calling `context.sync` in a loop, what's the preferred method of iterating over all items in a group which themselves have items which need to be synced? Here I'm finding each contentControl and finding its paragraphs and then that paragraph's range, all of which need to be themselves loaded.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Thank you Rick!